# How to compress contents in directory at FTP server in zip format and save it at FTPServer only using java

Tags: java

I have few directories inside a parent directory at FTP server, I want all those child directories to be zipped in single file and save it to at FTP server only

I have tried using FTPClient to download set of files from a particular directory and can compress them in local then could save back to FTPServer but i would like like to do it on the fly.

Like compressing contents inside parent directory and save the zip file to FTPServer itself